# What is wrong with my regex search string?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to search through thousands of HTML files to find the following structure:

```
<ul class="default-hidden" data-uuid="4c0c52f4e3f3498e855aacef3fa0c215">
                                            <li data-uuid="cf3ad198e1524569903f04e362b97ab2"><span class="default-hidden">Because a mix of physical and psychosocial answer choices does not exist, answer choices cannot be eliminated at this step. Move to
                                                Step 4.</span>
                                            </li>
                                        </ul>
```

I'm using the following regex string:

```
<ul class="default-hidden" data-uuid=".*">\s*<li data-uuid=".*"><span class="default-hidden">(.*)\s<\/span>\s*<\/li>\s*<\/ul>
```

It's not finding the text "Because a mix of physical and psychosocial answer choices does not exist, answer choices cannot be eliminated at this step. Move to Step 4." because of all the white space.

What do I need to adjust so it finds everything between the span and end-span including any white space or breaks?

Answer (score 0):

You don't match the `Step 4.` component, because it comes after the whitespace, and you're looking for a `</span>` immediately after that. Instead of `(.*)\s`, you're looking for `(.*)\s(.*)` (or similar).

```
<ul class="default-hidden" data-uuid=".*">\s*<li data-uuid=".*"><span class="default-hidden">(.*)\s(.*)<\/span>\s*<\/li>\s*<\/ul>
```

This can be seen working **[here](https://regex101.com/r/EN3YID/1/)**.